# Principal Component Analysis: Why Are Many Solutions Possible?

Tags: pca, matrix, linear-algebra

The following example is from chapter 2.12 of *Deep Learning*, by Goodfellow, Bengio, and Courville:

[image]
[image]

I don't understand what is meant by the very last part: "Many solutions are possible, because we can increase the scale of $\mathbf{D}_{:, i}$ if we decrease $c^i$ proportionally for all points."

I would appreciate it if people could please take the time to clarify this

Comment: If you multiple `c` by 10, you would also divide `D` by 10. That would give another solution. Think like 100 = a * b. You will have many solutions unless you constrain a and b.

Comment: @SmallChess I understand now. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PCA ([please go here, read and upvote](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/2691/1352)) takes a cloud of points in high-dimensional space and describes it in lower-dimensional space. In the two-dimensional case as in [amoeba's excellent illustration here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/140579/1352) (have you upvoted it yet?), this means that the first step is describing *how the cloud is oriented*. That is, we first find the *angle* at which the cloud can be "best" described as lying. This "angle-finding" is what $D$ does.

Having achieved this, we have to describe *where* along that angle the points lie (roughly, since we are approximating in order to compress information). And here, we have a choice of scale. We can measure how far out the line a given point lies in centimeters (so we might get a coordinate of 5.08) or in inches (getting a coordinate of 2). To resolve this, PCA decides that the angular scale must be "similar" to the original scale of the high-dimensional space we are working on; specifically that the matrix $D$ have unit length columns.